# How to transfer event(action) from internal to external component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

If i have such layout:
    -- App
      -- List
        -- Item
I want to select only one item, that make others disabled, how to pass the event from Item to App?

Ex.:

```
/* In App */
handleChecked: function() {}
<List onHandleChecked={this.handleChecked} />

/* In List Component */
<Item onChecked={this.props.onHandleChecked} />

/* In 
handleChecked: function() {
  // ajax query
  // check on this

  // turn off other items
  this.props.onChecked(...);
}
```

It seems not work.

**Final Problem**
Thanks for help...i found the final problem is the pointer `this`...

```
var LocaleList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var items = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <LocaleItem data={item} onMarkAsStd={this.props.onHandleOnMarkAsStd.bind(this)} />
            )
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <tbody>
                {items}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
})
```

Here, `items` require another bind(this)...or else, it won't get the property `onHandleOnMarkAsStd` :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `selected` item in the state of your `List`. And pass the `onClick` handler to the `Items`.

Here is the example (press `run`) and then click on the Item.

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
      List:
      <List items={[1, 2, 3]} />
    </div>
  }
})

var List = React.createClass({

   getInitialState() {
     return {
       selected: null,
     }
   },
   
   // data form child component 
   // this.props.onClick.bind(this, this.props.data)
   _handleClick(data) {
      this.setState({selected: data});
   },

   render() {
     var self = this;
     return <div> 
       {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
        return <Item onClick={self._handleClick} data={item} isSelected={self.state.selected == item} />;
   })}
     </div>
   }
});


var Item = React.createClass({
 
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this, this.props.data)}>Item #{this.props.data} - {this.props.isSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Disabled'}</div>
  }
})
                     
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your code. But your situation is both of two are connected. I'm following the tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: @Yarco, can you please tell me how can I change my code to disconnect the components. And if we will use the tutorial as an example, what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: oh, sorry. i clicked `enter` and it is harf submitted...I mean my components structures are like in the tutorial, app (contains a  list and a form), then the list contains the items, and i also follow the code to do the submission task in the app(not in the list, so the list itself is like an empty controller). So now i'm adding the logic like i said in the topic...  I mean, do we have the solution on passing the event to the top component (here, the app), or only have the way to the parent(list)?

Comment: There are couple solutions. (I will use my example) First, move `state` and `_handleClick(data)` from `<List />` to `<App />` and then pass this handler and state down to all the children components. So, you will have the selected item in the state of your master component. Second, you can use Flux. Move data items to the Store, in your `<App />` you need to subscribe to the Store changes, and call Actions when you click on the `<Item />`.

Comment: thanks for your help...i put the final problem in the topic, cause the code seems not display well here.

Comment: js `this` is too flexible, it can be seen everywhere but has different meanings...and when combined with JSX, it is hard to find out `where am i`...

Comment: You can use `self = this;` inside the `this.props.data.map(function() {...})`. I've updated my example.